# Bash to search and delete?

Tags: bash, file, search

I need a script that will search for a file in a applications directory and delete it. If it's not there it will continue with the install.

What I'm needing deleted:

```
/Applications/Cydia.app/Sections/Messages(D3@TH's-Repo).png
```

If that's not found I want it to continue on the install. If it finds that file I want it to delete it before continuing the installation.

This is what I've got:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/Applications/Cydia.app/Sections/Messages(D3@TH's-Repo).png"
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
    echo "$file delteling old icon"
    rm -rf /Applications/Cydia.app/Sections/Messages(D3@TH's-Repo).png

else
    echo "$file old icon deleted already moving on"
fi
```

Comment: With which part of this script creation are you struggling? Finding the file? Deleting it? Running the installer? If you share your code, we may be able to help you fix this.

Comment: I get a subprocess pre-installation script returned error exit status 2 and Sub-process /urs/bin/dpkg returned error code (1)

Comment: change the shebang to `/bin/bash -x` to enable debugging, run it and look at the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parentheses are used to start a subshell in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), so you'll need to put your filename in double-quotes (as you did in the file test).

Change the line:

```
rm -rf /Applications/Cydia.app/Sections/Messages(D3@TH's-Repo).png
```

To:

```
rm -rf "${file}"
```

And this will remove the file (assuming no permissions problems).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -e <your_file> ]; then
    rm -f <your_file>
 fi
```

this should do.

Comment: my problem now is terminal won't chmod it to 775 so i have to do it on my iPad by editing the permissions manually

Comment: I get syntax error near unexpected token "(" line 6 is rm -f /Applications/Cydia.app/Sections/Messages(D3@TH's-Repo).png how can I fix that error?

Comment: try \ before parenthesis as :-
/Applications/Cydia.app/Sections/Messages\\(D3@TH's-Repo\\).png